# Conditional format with large data fails and show error as "Selection is too large" in Excel 2007

Tags: excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I am facing a issue in paste special operation using conditional formats for large data in Excel 2007

I have uploaded a file at below given location.

http://sdrv.ms/1fYC9qE

The file contains two sheets, Sheet "Data" contains the data on which formats are to be applied and sheet "FormatTables" contains the format tables which contains conditional formating.

There are two table in "FormatTables" sheet. Both have some conditional formats applied on it.

**Case 1:**

1. Select the table range of Table1 i.e $A$2:$AV$2
2. Copy it
3. Goto Sheet "Data"
4. Select data area i.e $A$1:$AV$20664
5. Perform a paste special operation on full range and select "Formats" option while performing paste special.

**Result:**

It throws error as "Selection is too large"

**Case 2:**

1. Select the table range of Table2 i.e $A$5:$AV$5
2. Copy it
3. Goto Sheet "Data"
4. Select data area i.e $A$1:$AV$20664
5. Perform a paste special operation on full range and select "Formats" option while performing paste special.

**Result:**

Formats get applied successfully.

Both are the same format tables with same no of column and applied to same data range($A$1:$AV$20664) where one of the case works and another fails.

The only diffrence is Table1 has appliesTo range($A$2:$T$2) as partial of total table range($A$2:$AV$2) whereas the Table2 has appliesTo range($A$5:$AV$5) same as of its total table range($A$5:$AV$5)

*NOTE : This issue is only in Excel 2007*

Answer (score 0):

It is said that Excel 2007 supports formating for 8000 rows at a time. If destination table has 8000-16000 rows then you have to insert 1 more row in your format table i.e 2 rows. If 16000-24000 then table with 3 rows. In above case there are approx 20000 rows. So the format table should have 3 rows

like: A1:AV4

then try to copy that formating and apply

Solution Case 1:

1. Select the table range of Table1 i.e AV21 and drage it down to two row down
2. Select the table range of Table1 i.e $A$2:$AV$4
3. Copy it
4. Goto Sheet "Data"
5. Select data area i.e $A$1:$AV$20664
6. Perform a paste special operation on full range and select "Formats" option while performing paste special

Formats get applied successfully.

**I am still unaware then why in Case 2 it applies formats successfully.**